# How to link my own .css and .js to wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I´m trying add my own css a js code which should have influence on element in visual composer created by me. I don not want write my css to style.css of theme. I would rather add css and js with some code in `function.php`.

According to this I try to proceed: [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/)

That's what I'm trying to add (in `function.php`):

```
function theme_styles()  
{ 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'reference-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/own-vc-elements/references/reference-style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'reference-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/own-vc-elements/references/reference-script.js', array('jquery'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

But it still does not doing anything. What is wrong?

**EDIT: Without change. So this should itself add css and js into wordpress system isn't it? If there isn't any mistake.**

[Browser errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5N50.png)

Comment: Have you tried putting the wp_enqueue methods outside of the action?

Comment: Are you getting errors either in the browser's console or in the server's logs?

Comment: How you know they are not being loaded? The reference is not in the header?

Comment: Masiorama - Yes I tryed and results was same, j08691 - no errors, David Lee - reference-style is only name of file and i dont want load theme bych add link to header

Comment: Check HTML source head tag in your browser. Do you see reference-style.css or reference-script.js?

Comment: j08691 - finded errors, i did not understand, but now...   more in edit

Comment: Based on browser console error, php codes works properly and your assets included in your html head. This errors depends on your web server.

Comment: Make sure the path of file is specified right! Function is working as it needs to be but it cannot find the file in the path you have specified. You can check the path using Inspect Element under head Tag.

Comment: Yes I found reference-style.css and ...js in source head tag

Comment: Check your css & js files path and permissions.

Comment: Forbidden, so solution is set access to read...i suppose?

Comment: Set css & js files permissions to 644

Comment: got it, what about the folders where are files stored? can be 0754 for them?

Comment: New errors incomming.  more in edit - img

Comment: For security reasons don't give write permission to files and folders if it is not necessary.

Comment: Yea i got it. It wanted permission (execute on) on folders. Code 0755

Comment: New error message : `Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /domains/jirischaffer.cz/wp-content/themes/brando/own-vc-elements/references/reference-style.css on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe. ` Set your CSS and js files to 755 if it not works again check your .htaccess file.

Comment: Finally worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script depends on jquery use `wp_enqueue_script()` third argument as below.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'reference-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/own-vc-elements/references/reference-script.js', array('jquery'));
```

If is not works again check your script path and check your browser console for 404 error.

In `wp_enqueue_style()` function parameter replace `get_stylesheets_directory_uri()` with `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` - there is an extra `s` character -. Also note that you can use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

**update**

Above code solves the assets load problem.

Another problem in cases like this case is file permissions. Set read permission to files and its parents directory solves the problem.

Comment: Without change. So this should itself add css and js into wordpress system isn't it? If there isn't any mistake.

Comment: Parents directory must also have (execute on for others) set manually. It did not work until I set it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it like any other project, and then include it in your HTML using this function (The function will return a path to the current folder that has the php File.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>pathToFile"/>
```

More info:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/

Comment: But this must be added to <head> tags isnt it? That's not exactly what I'm looking for. I would like to have everything on one place. This method isnt useful when i want implement a bigger ammout of css and js.

Comment: This will be in Wordpress header file :)

Comment: This is really not the way to add scripts and styles to WP :(

Comment: Wordpres is about connecting backend with frontend. When I build theme my structure of files is like any other project. I am good at it.

Answer (score 0):

Took a look at your browser errors, your stylesheets are being found but permission is being denied (hence the 403 error).

This is likely due to a poorly configured security plugin you are using, some rogue .htaccess rule, or my guess, improperly configured file permissions.

Here is a guide that walks through the solutions for each of those issues: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-403-forbidden-error-in-wordpress/